# non interactive execution of bundle exec rake db:configure_admin

Tags: canvas-lms

I'm trying to automate installation of canvas lms, and I need to know how to run "bundle exec rake db:configure_admin" command in non-interactive mode as it asks me for admin email/password ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be done by setting the following environmental variables :

> CANVAS_LMS_ADMIN_EMAIL
>
> CANVAS_LMS_ADMIN_PASSWORD